# Unable to install theme with live-preview features

Tags: joomla-3.x, layout

I recently bought this template ("Beat" from WiselyThemes) and followed the instructions to make it look like the live preview the seller posted on Themeforest (http://preview.themeforest.net/item/beat-one-page-music-band-joomla-template/full_screen_preview/7723157?_ga=2.195573096.575021629.1660836699-2120608566.1660836699),
but still, on my site, it[image] keeps being empty, as you can see in the screenshot.
Do you have some advice on how to adjust the layout?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The name of the template implies that it's a one-page template, isn't it?

- Have you checked the sellers website for documentation?
- Have you contacted the seller for support?

Usually, to make content (articles or other content) available you'll need to:

- created some Articles in Joomla
- make them available via Menu Items. In this case probably Menu Item Type: Single Article and choose the articles that you have created.

Joomla's "Home" menu item is by default "Featured Articles". So in this case you'll probably just have to make your Articles "Featured".
Documentation: https://docs.joomla.org/Managing_the_Featured_Items

Comment: Thanks, I'll be checking